# Разбор по составу слова БЕРУШИ

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор

Слово *беруши* представляет собой сокращение от словосочетания *береги уши*. Верно ли в таком случае выделять в нём два корня:

```
бер/уш/и
```

по аналогии с другими сложносокращёнными словами или же в нём выделяется цельный корень *-беруш-*?

**П.С.** Было бы интересно найти ещё примеры подобных слов, не с продуктивным префиксоидом в начале слова (как в словах *фотоаппарат*, *автобиография* и подобных) или продуктивным суффиксоидом в конце (как *библиотека* или *психолог*), а именно сокращение от слов с устоявшимися корнями, не вызывающими споры об их морфемном статусе в РЯ.

**Обновление.** Воспользовавшись советом из ответа @Eleven_ Q _Eight, посмотрел разбор слов со схожим словообразованием у Тихонова:

```
глав/вра'ч/
глав/бу'х/
зав/хо'з/
за'в/у/ч/ (заведующий учебной частью)
```

Т.о. по аналогии в слове *беруши* можно выделить два корня:

```
бер/уш/и
```

Answer (score 2):

***Беруши*** – новое слово в нашем языке. Говорят, что термин придумал наш ученый-химик И́. В. Петря́нов-Соколо́в, но это, возможно, только версия.

Интересно же вот что: очень многие пользователи русского языка  **не понимают происхождение этого слова.** Например, встречаются такие цитаты:

(1) Если бы меня спросили, я бы с полной уверенностью ответила, что слово это **иностранного происхождения**, возможно французское или еще какое-нибудь. Поэтому для меня было полнейшей неожиданностью узнать, что "беруши" – это сокращенное от "береги уши", представляете?! Не знаю, как вы, а **я в полнейшем шоке**, для меня это было неожиданно, мягко говоря".

(2) Кстати, слово "беруши" – оно вовсе **не восточное,** как я думал раньше.

Другими словами, происхождение этого слова как бы ушло в историю,  если мы не можем считать информацию о нем с его состава, не можем понять его значение, не обращаясь к специальным этимологическим и историческим источникам.  И тогда возникает вопрос: **имеет ли вообще смысл делить его на морфемы, как вы считаете?**

Я полагаю, что корень в нем  беруш-, не бер/уш/и.  Мы не можем считать с форманта БЕР значение "беречь", а УШ напоминает суффикс, а не второй корень.

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться. Для производства дериватов в большинстве случаев достаточно лишь основы, которая действительно будет *-беруш-*. Но полноценный морфологический и словообразовательный анализ иногда невозможны без привлечения дополнительных сведений об языковой единице, а здесь происхождение от словосочетания хоть и не очевидно, но легко и вполне однозначно подтверждается при изучении справочной информации.

Comment: Да. подтверждается, но разве вас не смущает, что носители языка думают, что это иностранное слово, что они не воспринимают его морфемный состав как нечто значащее. А справочная литература - это уже информация о происхождении слова, которое изучает этимология. Например, вал и волна - это исторически однокоренные слова, но мы считаем ,что волна - непроизводное слово в современном языке.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос в том, является ли аббревиация способом словообразования. Здесь мнения лингвистов расходятся.

По мнению многих лингвистов, такие дериваты как "журфак", "завхоз" при аббревиации теряют связь с исходным словосочетанием, поэтому в них выделяется один корень. Теряя связь, они становятся одной единицей.

Если придерживаться той точки зрения, что связь не теряется, выделяется 2 корня.

Примеры: главврач, завуч.

В случае с **беруши** наблюдается сложение цельного слова с компонентом. Примеры: оргстекло, стенгазета.

Comment: Благодарю за содержательный ответ. Действительно, посмотреть разборы аналогичных по словообразованию слов в данном случае — самый верный способ.

Comment: Посмотрел разборы аналогичных по словообразованию слов и обновил ответ.